# Display Data In Real Time With Django

Tags: python, django

I have a simulator application that continuously spits out data, formatted in JSON, to a given host name and port number (UDP). I would like to be able to point the simulator output to a Django web application so that I can monitor/process the data as it comes in.

How do I receive and process data in real time using Django? What tools or packages are available to accomplish this? I did come across this answer: [How to serve data from UDP stream over HTTP in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768019/how-to-serve-data-from-udp-stream-over-http-in-python), but I don't completely understand.

Ex: Similar to this page: http://money.cnn.com/data/markets/

ALSO, I don't need to store any of the streaming data in a database. I just need to perform lookups based on the streaming data. Maybe it's not a Django issue at all?

Comment: I recommend you [SwampDragon](http://swampdragon.net/)

Comment: did you find any solution for this, I am looking for the same thing now.

Comment: @Yashwanth My solution to this was not to use Django. While you can use websockets or javascript alongside Django to deal with this kind of problem,  it's probably not the most canonical way.

Comment: @denvaar I am using channels in django and it works as of now, do you think its not a good solution.

Comment: @Yashwanth yes.

Comment: @denvaar what is the reason ?

Comment: @Yashwanth Channels makes it so that Django works with things other than plain HTTP requests, including websockets. Although Django Channels is a fairly young project, I feel like it would still be a reliable way to handle this sort of thing.

Comment: @denvaar yeah, thanks a lot for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript.
Create a webpage with all the results, and then use javascript to collect the data from the page, and update it every X seconds.

Have the webpage be the JSON data, and the javascript grab it an interpret it.
[get html code using javascript with a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375461/get-html-code-using-javascript-with-a-url)

Then update the page using javascript. ww3 schools has great JS tutorials