# Is it good idea to create two different files for reading and writing?

Tags: java, file, file-io, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I am building a basic bank application, although the usage of the java language is intermediate level.
There I am using file input and output a lots. Along the way some questions has popped up in my mind about the `file-i/o` in java.

1) What if I create two different text file for writing and reading objects? Does it make any difference?

2) How about the specifying path (or giving file name), what if I use `//` instead of `\\`?

3) Do I necessarily need to create a new file object like this: `File file=new File("C://Users//Documents//NetBeansProjects//BankFile_assignment.txt");` in my specific case?

Last but not least if you may wonder about my file-i/o class:

```
    public class ReaderWriter {

    public void writeToFile(List<BankAccount> accounts) {
        try {
            File file = new File("C://Users//Documents//NetBeansProjects//BankFile_assignment.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(accounts);//take the arrayList 
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<BankAccount> readFromFile() {
        List<BankAccount> readData = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("C://Users//Documents//NetBeansProjects//BankFile_assignment.txt");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            readData = (List<BankAccount>) ois.readObject();

            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return readData;

    }
}
```

Comment: That depends. If you allow your program to simultaneously read and write it will probably be a bad solution with one file(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751734/how-do-filesystems-handle-concurrent-read-write)
Have you thought about using a Database? Using MySQL is in my opinion always easier then using a file to store your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Better way is to use databases (mySQL, SQLite,...) to access easily to all your datas without I/O worries.

2) If your application might work on different Operating Systems, a safe way to avoid any trouble with the specific symbol of system ( `\` on Windows, `/` on Unix, Mac) is to use `File.separator` for example. [More about this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths) .

3) It must work on Windows, but fails on Unix. You can use (with adaptation for path) this instead of:  `File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+ File.separator + BankFile_assignment.txt);` [See this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) .