# Python threading:Is it okay to read/write multiple mutually exclusive parts of a file concurrently?

Tags: python, multithreading, file, io

I know we can guarantee correctness either by locking or using a specialized thread whose sole job is to read/write and communicate with it through queue.

But this approach seems logically ok, so I want to avoid implementing them, specially because both has performance penalty.

Comment: I think it would help if you give a short code sample of how you plan to accomplish it. Also run a test of it yourself and see what happens.

Comment: It gives right answer in tests. But isn't mulit-threaded programs famous for pretending to be correct when it actually isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no.

Concurrent reading and writing behavior is heavily dependent on both the underlying operating system **and** filesystem.

You *may* be able to get something working by reading and writing chunks that are both a multiple of the underlying block size and are block-aligned.  But you are likely in the world of "undefined behavior".

See also, related question:  [How do filesystems handle concurrent read/write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751734/how-do-filesystems-handle-concurrent-read-write)

Answer (score 0):

The OP wants **multithreaded access** to a file, not across multiple programs or even a network.
Therefore I say **YES** you can do that.
For instance:

```
def job_handler(id, job_queue):
    fh = open('test')
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        try:
            job = job_queue.get_nowait()
            # Do the job
            #   fh.read(job.offset, job.size)
            #     Work with data
            #   fh.write(job.offset, job.size)

        except queue.Empty:
            fh.close()
            exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    job_queue = mp.Queue()
    for job in [(0, 100), (200, 100), (200, 100), (100, 100), (300, 100), (300, 100), (400, 100), (500, 100), (400, 100), (600, 100)]:
        job_queue.put( job )

    processes = []
    for p in range(1,4):
        processes.append( mp.Process(target = job_handler, args = (p, job_queue) ) )

    for p in processes:
        p.start()
        time.sleep(0.1)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

In order to demonstrate what I mean with **risk**, i have duplicated jobs in the job_queue.
Watch out the line **[CLASH]**, without **control** there is a rw of process 3 within a rw of process 2.

Output:

```
Start Job handler 1
Start Job handler 2
1: read offset=0
    2: read offset=200
Start Job handler 3
        3: read offset=200
[CLASH] offset:200 read by process:{2}
1: write offset=0
1: read offset=100
        3: write offset=200
    2: write offset=200
  ...
exit(0) job_handler 3
exit(0) job_handler 2
exit(0) job_handler 1
```

Conclusion, if you don't have such duplicate parts you can do it without locking.
I would suggest to use a File Handle per process/thread.

Comment: This contradicts the previous answer, doesn't it?