# prevent from concurrent writing to the one file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Good day everyone.

I would be very grateful if you were able to help me with this problem I stuck in. I administrate Linux Server, so are there any ways to prevent from concurrent(multiple) modifications of file from different users?

Thank you.

Yes, I have read about chattr, but prevents files from deleting I guess.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751734/how-do-filesystems-handle-concurrent-read-write)

Comment: In general, mandatory file locking is not reliable and considered harmful. :-)